# PHP Form - Uploading Files, wanting to use Silex but not FormBuilder

Tags: php, file, upload, silex, mustache.php

I'm using Silex to build an app, though it's not the typical Silex setup.

I've got Mustache as the templating engine.

I'm not using Doctrine for ORM / DBAL, I'm using Capsule [(Silex-Eloquent)](https://github.com/bradberger/silex-eloquent), and am having some serious trouble wrapping my head around this.

Currently I have a form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="app.php/listing" method="POST" id="listing-submit">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="title">Listing Title</label>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input id="title" class="form-control" type="text" size="40" autocomplete="off"
                           data-encrypted-name="title"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="description">Description</label>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <textarea id="description" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Images</label>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" multiple/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
```

Which I'm using to select files, though, all the examples I've seen thus far of Silex and file uploading, uses something I'm not to familiar with, and not sure I can make it adapt to my use: The FormBuilder, FormBuilderInterface, registering custom types and all that jazz...

This is the Controller-Part so far:

```
$app->post("/plisting", function () use ($app) { 

  // $params = $request->all(); 
  $request = $app['request']; 
  $title = $request->get('title'); 
  $description = $request->get('description'); 
  $image = $request->files->get('image'); 

  // $file->move(__DIR__ . '/files', $file->getClientOriginalName()); // return "done"; 

  return "<pre>Class for request: " . get_class($request) . "<br>Title: $title <br>Description: $description<br>File: $image </pre>"; 
});
```

Note, I'm using ajax to handle to file uploads.

I'm curious if someone is able to walk me through using the setup in place and silex to upload files, or if I should just use non-framework PHP to handle the file uploads?

I'm at a mental block here, and could use a hand; Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, could you please provide some code from your ListingController? Where and how do you handle the POST-request for a new listing?

Comment: `$app->post("/plisting", function () use ($app) {
//    $params = $request->all();

    $request = $app['request'];
    $title = $request->get('title');
    $description = $request->get('description');

    $image = $request->files->get('image');


    return "<pre>Class for request: " . get_class($request) . "<br>Title: $title<br>Description: $description<br>File: $image
</pre>";

//    $file->move(__DIR__ . '/files', $file->getClientOriginalName());
//    return "done";
});
`
The request param doesn't have any return for the file, though the title and description elements are both visible.

Comment: Please don't use the comment-field for important code-blocks. I edited your question and hopefully the edit will be accepted.

Comment: Oh! Thank you, sorry for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to send files to the server, the browser has to encode its data using *multipart/form-data*, so you should just try to add the attribute`enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your form (which currently is missing).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that. I'm testing it now and seeing if it works! :)

Comment: Well it happens to all of us :-) BTW, if my answer helped you, remember to [accept it as a valid answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) in order to close the question.